# Custom Category Page Layout Static Block to bottom

Tags: magento-1.9, category, layout, catalog

When you select: Category>Display Settings>Display Mode>Static Block and Products the Static block that is selected gets displayed above the products by default.
For some pages I want the static block to be diplayed **below** the products. I would like to be able to do this from the Custom Design Tab by adding a Custom Layout Update. Here is the code from my catalog.xml

```
<catalog_category_default translate="label">
    <label>Catalog Category (Non-Anchor)</label>
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml">
            <action method="unsetChild"><child>category_filter</child></action>
            <block type="core/text_list" name="catalog.leftnav.state.renderers" as="state_renderers" />
        </block>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
                <action method="setDefaultDirection"><dir>desc</dir></action>
                <block type="core/text_list" name="product_list.name.after" as="name.after" />
                <block type="core/text_list" name="product_list.after" as="after" />
                <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                    <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                    <!-- The following code shows how to set your own pager increments -->
                    <!--
                        <action method="setDefaultListPerPage"><limit>4</limit></action>
                        <action method="setDefaultGridPerPage"><limit>9</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>2</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>4</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>6</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>8</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit" translate="label"><mode>list</mode><limit>all</limit><label>All</label></action>
                    -->
                </block>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action>
                <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
    <reference name="main_top">
        <block type="core/template" name="filter.one" template="typostores/filter/filterone.phtml"
               before="-">
            <action method="insert"><child>catalog.leftnav</child></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_default>
```

The line relating to the static block being displayed is:

```
<block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
```

And I need it displayed after the product list block.

I know how to edit the catalog.xml to display it like this on all pages but I only want it on a few hence why I would like to add a Custom Layout Update.

Please Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to edit `catalog/category/view.phtml` for this, not the layout file.

In `view.phtml`, you can see this:

```
<?php if($this->isContentMode()): ?>
    <?php echo $this->getCmsBlockHtml() ?>

<?php elseif($this->isMixedMode()): ?>
    <?php echo $this->getCmsBlockHtml() ?>
    <?php echo $this->getProductListHtml() ?>

<?php else: ?>
    <?php echo $this->getProductListHtml() ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

You will want to add your condition for `<?php echo $this->getCmsBlockHtml() ?>` like this:

```
<?php $categories = array('1' => '1', '2' => '2', '4' => '4'); //your list of categories?>
<?php if(in_array(Mage::registry('current_category')->getId(), $categories)):?>
    <?php if($this->isContentMode()): ?>
        <?php echo $this->getCmsBlockHtml() ?>
    <?php elseif(!$this->isMixedMode()): ?>
        <?php echo $this->getProductListHtml() ?>
    <?php else: ?>
        <?php echo $this->getProductListHtml() ?>
        <?php echo $this->getCmsBlockHtml() ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php else:?>
    <?php if($this->isContentMode()): ?>
        <?php echo $this->getCmsBlockHtml() ?>
    <?php elseif($this->isMixedMode()): ?>
        <?php echo $this->getCmsBlockHtml() ?>
        <?php echo $this->getProductListHtml() ?>
    <?php else: ?>
        <?php echo $this->getProductListHtml() ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Note: if `Mage::registry('current_category')->getId()` doesn't gives you current category ID then you would want to use this `$this->getLayout()->getBlock('category.products')->getCurrentCategory();`.
This should work.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Small syntax error after `//your list of categories` you need `?>`. Could you explain something for me. I believe mixed mode is  display Static Block and Products but if the category id is in the array it runs the else: option. Why is that??

Comment: If product id is in the array then it shouldn't run `else`. My guess is `Mage::registry('current_category')->getId()` is not returning value.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific it runs: `<?php else: ?>
        <?php echo $this->getProductListHtml() ?>
        <?php echo $this->getCmsBlockHtml() ?>` instead of the `MixedMode()`

Comment: That means, in your category you haven chosen to have `static block and catalog` together.

Comment: But I have it set to `static block and catalog` thats what I can't figure out. But it is still renedering the Block after the Products which is what I want just don understand it???

Comment: Isn't that what you wanted. Sorry, I am getting confused with your qst. If you choose to have both then it will display both. If you don't choose both and only catalog then it will fall to `!$this->isMixedMode()` section.